# Bash replace line using sed and 2 variables

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sed, scripting

I am trying to replace a line in a file using sed and 2 variables. I tried this:

```
    varFind=$(echo "cfg_dir=/usr/local/.file1.cfg")
    varReplace=$(echo "cfg_dir=/usr/dir1/file2.cfg")

    sed -i "s/${varFind}/${varReplace}/" /usr/local/file.txt
```

But it keeps throwing this:

```
    user@localhost:~# ./script.sh sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'
```

What am I doing wrong? I've looked and it appears to be right to me.

Comment: Add real string1 and string2 to your question.

Comment: The example you have works as expected @Cyrus assumes that there is a strange char in `varFind` of `varReplace`,  '/' for example.

Comment: So if my variables were something like `varFind=$(echo "/usr/local/test.txt")` there would be issues?

Comment: Yes, `/` is used to separate the parameters for `s`. You can use another separator like `%` instead.

Comment: But what is the string in `varFind` is something like `cfg_dir=/usr/local`? How would I get around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to fix your problem is to change the separator for the `s` command. Change your `sed` command to this:

```
sed -i "s%${varFind}%${varReplace}%" /usr/local/file.txt
```

This works as long as your variables don't contain `%`.

Comment: Thank you, I am still new to bash and it's taking me a little bit to get the hang of it.